# when i click on menu button my tailwind css is not working on my react.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {AiOutlineMenu,AiOutlineSearch,AiOutlineClose,AiFillTag} from 'react-icons/ai'
import {BsFillCartFill,BsPerson} from "react-icons/bs"
const TopNav = () => {
    const [sideNav,setSideNav]=useState(false)
   
        <button className="bg-orange-700 text-white hidden md:flex items-center py-2 px-4 rounded-full"><BsFillCartFill size={20}/> Cart</button>
        {
            sideNav ? (
                <div className="bg-black/60 fixed w-full h-screen z-10 top-0 left-0"></div>
            ):("")
        }
        <div className={
        sideNav
        ? "fixed top-0 left-0 w-[300px] h-screen bg-whhite z-10 duration-300"
        : "fixed top-0 left-[-100%] w-[300px] h-screen bg-whhite z-10 duration-300"}>

        <AiOutlineClose size={25} onClick={()=>setSideNav(!sideNav)} />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopNav;
```

i want that when i click menu button width will be white in 300px and background will be black but it not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is wrong so it is not working, recheck the class name. Try extension [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) for easier when using tailwind

```
<div className={
        sideNav
        ? "fixed top-0 left-0 w-[300px] h-screen bg-white z-10 duration-300"
        : "fixed top-0 left-[-100%] w-[300px] h-screen bg-white z-10 duration-300"}>
```